# Photoshop: how to add an anchor point at a exact size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Let's say I have a shape. A simple shape, like a rectangle. And I need to add an anchor point at an exact point of a line. I can do this by doing some simple math and use guides to mark that point, and of course it works. Or I could just zoom in until I see pixel by pixel and then place the anchor even without guides.

However, I was wondering if there's a way to place an anchor by adding a numeric input. Say you right click on a path and there's an option *(if it exists probably with some key(s) combination)* to add the anchor at `X px` or `X %` from the `top or bottom or left or right or beginning of path or relative size` or whatever.

**Does this (or something like this) exists in Photoshop?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It does not exist.

There *may* be some third party plug-n somewhere but that's unlikely since Photoshop is *raster* based and not really designed for mathematical precision. Illustrator won't do this either, but there are plug-ins for Illustrator which, if they don't do this directly, would make it much easier to accomplish.